# Audio Clip from Audio Source not playing

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a VR game with hand tap sounds. I am trying to make 2 scripts to handle the sounds. The first one I attach to an object and I define the sound type. The second one handles playing it. The problem is that the sound is not playing, even though I have the audio clip in the audio source and I have no errors.

Script 1:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class HitSounds : MonoBehaviour
{
enum HitSoundType
{
    None,
    Wood,
    Rock,
    Metal,
    Grass
};

[SerializeField]
HitSoundType hitSoundType = new HitSoundType();
public HitSoundManager hitSoundManager;

private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("HandTag"))
    {
        switch (hitSoundType)
        {
            case HitSoundType.Grass:
                hitSoundManager.wood.Play();
                break;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Script 2:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class HitSoundManager : MonoBehaviour
{
public AudioSource wood;
void playWood()
{
    wood.Play();
}
}
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: You should ensure hitSoundType is correctly linked to `HitSoundManager` in Unity Editor. You also made a `playWood` function that is not being used anywhere, why? Why not do `hitSoundManager.PlayWood()` in `OnTriggerEnter`? Ensure you make `PlayWood` a `public void`, also.